# Secondary Domain in Google Apps Deleted and unable to create it back

Tags: google-workspace, domain

After I created the secondary domain, I found I had added a `www` in front of the secondary domain and I just deleted the secondary domain because of my mistake. When I tried to recreate it with the same domain name, it said:

> you have already have a domain or alias in this name

Should I wait for 24 hours to take effect. Is it possible to create a secondary domain on the same name in that same Google Apps account.

Comment: what do you mean by `create a secondary domain on the same name in that same Google Apps account`?

Answer (score 1):

You should wait as stated [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/56238?hl=en):

> ... please wait up to 24 hours from the time of deletion (or 7 days if you purchased your account from a reseller) ...